# How can I have a script running a live-server and execute commands after that?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, gulp

I'm creating a terminal script on my mac to initialize a repository from Github.
I want the following tasks to be done:

- cloning the repo
- creating basic files and folders
- launch gulp ( with a live server)
- open chrome
- push the first commit

My problem is that  when the gulp command is executed, it blocks the rest of the script, because the server is launched. I've tried to use `gulp &` to run it in background, but when I do this I can't figure out how to stop it.

Here is my code :

```sh
# Everything has been created above

code .
gulp &

# My commands to launch chrome and push a commit on Github
chrome localhost:1234
push initial commit
```

thanks for your help !

Comment: A straightforward way of doing this is assigning `gulp`'s PID to a variable (`gulp &; pid=$!`) and when you need to stop it `kill -9 $pid`.

Comment: Thank you for your help oguzismail, but I still get an error : `syntax error near unexpected token `;'
/usr/local/bin/repinit: line 111: `gulp &; pid=$!'`

Comment: oh yeah sorry, remove semicolon

Comment: Oh ok thought it was important to put it ! thanks !